# Is it okay to use patch for full update instead of put?

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, patch, put

I am using Django and DRF for APIs. Suppose I have an object with three fields (name, password, email). When a user wants to update his name, password and email at the same time, is it okay for me to send a `PATCH` request instead of a `PUT` request? What are the downfalls?

I feel this is more convenient than checking if the user is updating all fields, and if he is, using a `PUT` request, but if he's not, using a `PATCH`.

Checking if the object exists is already taken care of in the backend, and when creating objects, I use `CREATE / POST` instead of `PUT` because it is more convenient for me.

Edit: I am using AngularJS's `PATCH`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#patch to send content to the backend, which is handled by DRF Viewset (which handles `PATCH` requests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to use PATCH. However, note that it will not check for required fields as opposed to PUT.

Answer (score 0):

It's not OK to use PATCH unless you use a media type that has defined semantics for PATCH. "application/json" does not.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?eid=3169:

> If the operation does not modify the resource identified by the
>   Request-URI in a predictable way that's defined by the semantics
>   of the PATCH media type, POST should be considered instead of
>   PATCH or PUT.

FWIW, see RFC 6902 and RFC 7386 for types you could use.

Comment: Hm, I'm not too sure what you mean by "media type that has defined semantics for `PATCH` but I am using AngularJS's `PATCH`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#patch to send content to the backend, which is handled by DRF (which handles `PATCH` requests). Is this okay?

Comment: No, if it uses application/json. There needs to be a specification that says -- independently of implementations -- what the semantics of that request are.